# Hypertwistors and matrices

Tags: twistor

Just as twistors can be understood as certain objects invariant under SU(2,2), and SU(2,2/N) are the corresponding to supertwistors in supermatrices:

What is the fundamental matrix invariance applying to [hypertwistors](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=hypertwistors)?